# Issue sending audio data to a server using Android MediaRecorder

Tags: python, android, kotlin, tcp

I am making a simple app that starts recording using MediaRecorder when a button is pressed and then ends recording when another button is pressed. After this, it sends the data to a remote server (in this case it's currently my PC) and that remote server turns it into a sound file that can be listened to. For whatever reason, the server connection works but the file is extremely small (like 2kb no matter what I do). I'm new to this whole thing (Android dev and network connections) so I may be missing over some things. Was wondering if anyone has a solution.

```
class MediaRecorder(app: Application) {
    private val bufferSize: Int
    private lateinit var audioRecord: AudioRecord
    private val sampleRate: Int
    private val channelConfig: Int
    private val audioFormat: Int
    private val app = app;

    init{
        // Configure audio recording parameters
        sampleRate = 16000 // Adjust as needed
        channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
        audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT

        // Calculate the buffer size
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat) * 4


    }

    // called when button is pressed
    fun startRecording(){

        // I have already granted permission in main
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                app.applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {}

        audioRecord = AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            sampleRate,
            channelConfig,
            audioFormat,
            bufferSize
        )
        audioRecord.startRecording()
    }

    // called when stop button is pressed
    fun stopRecording(){
        audioRecord.stop()


        //Create a buffer to read audio data
        val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)

        Log.i("Audio", buffer.size.toString())

        // Read audio data from AudioRecord
        val bytesRead = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
        Log.i("Audio", "Bytes read are$bytesRead")

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // Send the audio data to the server
            sendByteArrayToServer(buffer)
        } else {
            Log.e("Audio", "No audio data recorded.")
        }
        audioRecord.release()
    }
}
```

here below is the code for the sending to server.

```
fun sendByteArrayToServer(byteArray: ByteArray) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val serverAddress = "myIPaddressistypicallyhere"
            val serverPort = 9999 

            val socket = Socket(serverAddress, serverPort)
            val outputStream: OutputStream = socket.getOutputStream()

            // Check if the byteArray is not null and has data
            if (byteArray.isNotEmpty()) {
                outputStream.write(byteArray)
                outputStream.flush()
                Log.i("Server", "Byte array sent successfully")
            } else {
                Log.i("Server", "Byte array is empty or null")
            }

            // Close the socket when done
            socket.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle any exceptions here
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("Server", "Error sending byte array to server: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}
```

below i have python code that is my "server".

```
import socket

# Define the host and port on which the server will listen
host = '0.0.0.0'  # Listen on all available network interfaces
port = 9999

# Sample rate and number of channels (modify as needed)
sample_rate = 16000
channels = 1

# Calculate the byte rate and block alignment based on the sample rate and channels
byte_rate = sample_rate * channels * 2  # Assuming 16-bit audio
block_alignment = channels * 2  # 16-bit audio

# Create a socket object
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the host and port
server_socket.bind((host, port))

# Listen for incoming connections
server_socket.listen(1)  # Maximum 1 client connection in the queue

print(f"Server listening on port {port}")

while True:
    # Accept a client connection
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print(f"Accepted connection from {client_address}")

    # Create a file to save the received audio data
    audio_file = open("received_audio.pcm", "wb")  # Use the appropriate file format

    # Receive and save audio data in chunks
    receiving_audio = True
    while receiving_audio:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)  # Adjust the buffer size as needed

        if not data:
            receiving_audio = False  # Exit the inner loop when no data is received

        audio_file.write(data)

    # Close the audio file and client socket
    audio_file.close()
    client_socket.close()

    print("PCM audio data received and saved as 'received_audio.pcm'")
```

I've tried some debugging statements and I just don't understand why the byte array is sending over such a small file.

Comment: Do not send your bytes to a server. Much too complicated at start. Just save them to file and play that file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.